# Installing deap using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, deap

An exception occurs while installing a package using pip. I tried installing deap package.
How can fixed it?

```
\Local\Programs\Python\Python38>pip install deap
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/deap/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/deap/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/deap/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/deap/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)'))': /simple/deap/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/deap/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/deap/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deap
ERROR: No matching distribution found for deap
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1108)'))) - skipping
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a internet proxy configured at the Config Panel -> Internet Options? If so disable it and try again. If it then times out, add the proxy on the command line using `--proxy http://address:port`

src : https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9568

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

Download package corresponding to your os from here https://pypi.org/simple/deap/

open terminal/cmd

cd into downloads directory

then pip install "deep--.whl"